# Как правильно реализовать округление числа в данной программе?

Tags: java, алгоритм

Сейчас решаю задачу, вроде всё реализовал верно, но тест не проходит.

Суть задания следующая:

> Округлить все элементы матрицы до целого числа.
>
> Использовать округление к ближайшему целому — число округляется до
>   целого, модуль разности с которым у этого числа минимален:
>
> если N+1 знак < 5, то N-ый знак сохраняют, а N+1 и все последующие
>   обнуляются если N+1 знак ≥ 5, то N-ый знак увеличивают на единицу, а
>   N+1 и все последующие обнуляют.

Вот мой код

```
public static void task22 () {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    int n = Integer.parseInt (scan.nextLine ());
    double[][] matrix = new double[n][n];

    System.out.println (n);
    System.out.println("\t");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = Double.parseDouble (scan.next ());
            System.out.print (Math.round (matrix[i][j]) + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println ("\n\t");
    }
}
```

**Вопрос:** как сделать чтобы -1.5 округлялось до 2, а не до 1?

[image: Тест]

Comment: Округлять по модулю, а потом знак возвращать

Comment: как сделать чтобы -1.5 округлялось до 2, а не до 1?
может до -2?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
Math.signum(number) * Math.round(Math.abs(number))
```

Answer (score 1):

Для чисел меньше нуля - смените знак, округлите, смените знак опять...

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    int n = Integer.parseInt (scan.nextLine ());
    double[][] matrix = new double[n][n];

    System.out.println (n);
    System.out.println("\t");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = Double.parseDouble (scan.next ());
            BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(matrix[i][j]).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            System.out.print (bigDecimal.toString() + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println ("\n\t");
    }

}
```